Deserializing an Edm.Date from OData endpoint to a DateOnly
I have a .Net 8 app that is retrieving data from an OData endpoint using the Simple.OData.Client.  The data being returned has several date only fields that are returned. When I try to access those fields I get an exception Object of type Microsoft.OData.Edm.Date cannot be converted to type System.DateOnly.
I have tried a custom Json converter but I'm not sure how I apply it to data being retrieved via the Simple.OData.Client. I am using System.Text.Json for serializing and deserializing.
Any thoughts on how to overcome the error?
